# Gluon mobile, how to safely store the login data on the client application?

Tags: java, password-protection, gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to create an client application with `gluon mobile` for android and desktop.
The app asks the user to input the login credentials and stores it for future logins. The login credentials are used for logging on to the serever. But I'm concerned about password protection in the client application and I could not find a solution.

What would be a possible solution to store the password secure?

The only way for login is username and password. Facebook or other authentications methods are not supported.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database. In short: create another column called `salt` that generates random fixed length string per user and concat that to the passowrd and hash it using `md5` or `sha`

Comment: I edited my question because it was maybe not clear that the problem is in the client application and not on the server side. If it is possible to authenticate with the mh5 hash then I should store the mh5 hash secure in client application.